# Difference Injective vs Bijective functions?

Tags: functions

Whats the difference between injective and bijective functions, is it because there are elements in the codomain that are unmapped in injective but not bijective functions?

If so can there be elements of domains that are unmapped?

Comment: *Yes*, injective functions need not attain all elements in the codomain. But they can. Bijective function must attain all. *No*, all elements of the domain must be mapped.

Comment: @M.Winter can I ask why are they defined so such that codomain can have unmapped values but not domains, what's the intuition behind it?

Comment: I think the intuition is that you should think about a function as a process. You put something in, you get something out. You can study function/processes without fully understanding them. You should know what you can put in (e.g. what is the $\sin$ of a crocodile?). But because a function might be *very* complex it is often hard to know exactly what comes out. But we still want to talk about them even when not knowing what can come out. So we leave it open. And when we someday know exactly what can come out we can always shrink the codomain to fit this result. Then the function is injective.

Comment: @M.Winter are they used in more advanced courses in computer science,
 and if so what are they? (asking coz im an c.sci undergraduate studying discrete maths currently)

Comment: Functions you mean? They are everywhere. Nothing works without functions in any science. Whether the question of injectivity/bijectivity will be relevant depends on your course of study.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f:A\to B$ is injective if different $x\in A$ have different images $f(x)\in B$

All elements of $A$ **MUST** be mapped, otherwise $f$ is not a function

It is surjective when $A$ is mapped onto all $B$ by $f$. In other words $f(A)=B$

Bijective means injective + surjective.

There are functions which are injective but not bijective for instance $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$

all $x<0$ in the co-domain have no preimage

usually a function can be given  surjectivity "shrinking" the co-domain $B$  and taking $f(A)\subset B$  as the new codomain

In the example above just taking $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ $f(x)=x^2 $ becomes a bijection and therefore can be inverted $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$

hope this is useful

Comment: can an injective function have an inverse function/is it invertible?

Comment: It must be surjective, too, all element of codomain must be image of some $x$. Otherwise inverting, when the codomain becomes the domain of the inverse, there would be elements with no image and therefore not a function. Think to my example $x^2$. If we don't shrink the codomain we would have the square root with domain $\mathbb{R}$ but $\sqrt{}$ of negatives don't exist and we would have a non-function